# sql server 2008 inistallation - tool to send notification

Tags: sql-server

implementing a new database. I want all database administrators to be notified if resources on the SQL Server are running low.
what tool do you use to send the notification

Comment: Please check the below link 

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1523/how-to-setup-sql-server-alerts-and-email-operator-notifications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use the SQL Server Agent/ Jobs for something like that. In the Management Studio, connect to your server. In the list on the right you'll see SQL Server Agent.

Click that and then click on Jobs. 
Right click and create a new Job with a name. [image]

In the dialog box on the left, you'll see "Steps" and "Alerts". 
Steps is where you'd put your code to determine if the box is running low on resources (there are plenty of sources around for that code). 
[image]

Alerts is where you can build your list of administrators to email by clicking "Add Alert" and giving the alert a name. In the New Alert dialog, click "Response" and add the people in "Notify Operators" whom you want contacted.

[image]

Obviously there's more to talk about, but this should get you started.